# Is it possible to view multiple tuner runs at once on tensorboard hparams tab?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorboard, hyperparameters, keras-tuner

I'm using Keras tuner to do hyperparameter optimization on a particular hypermodel which is then trained for different cases (i.e. different houses). My goal for now is to get an easy, straightforward visualisation of what generally works, and what doesn't. The Tensorboard Hparams tab seems perfect for this, except that it only shows one run of tuner at once - only one house. The scalars tab shows all runs at once, but not the Hparams tab - tuner is running for 100 trials for each house, and the Hparams tab shows only 100 trials total. Is there a way to change this?